# How can we increase http response content length in .Net Core 3.1 with API using appsettings.json

Tags: api, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created an API in dot net core 3.1 but it's not working with huge data but when we decrease response length it's working properly.
Can we increase Http response length in .Net Core 3.1 API?